# How do I install the facebook sdk for ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, installation

How do I install the Facebook SDK for iOS?

The download from the facebook developer website is failing, every time.

So, I got it from github:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

But, I don't know what script to run, file to execute, thing to build, or...anything, to get to the next step in the process, which is to add the built facebook sdk to my xcode project. Anything I try to run (e.g. sh build_all.sh, etc.) doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go here and click download: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios
2. Install package.
3. Find FacebookSDK folder, and in there you have FacebookSDK.framework.
4. Go to your project, open settings, go to Info. Add 2 variables to Custom iOS Target Properties.
   a) FacebookAppID (String), with your app id from the facebook: e.g.
   543523965389292
   b) FacebookDisplayName (String) with your name you want to display.
5. In the same Info tab expand URL Types and add new one. Paste in the URL Scheme fb_APP_ID_, e.g. fb543523965389292.
6. Go to Build Phases, expand Link Binary With Libraries. Add the FacebookSDK.framework from the point 2.
7. In your AppDelegate.m add:
   `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`. And replace function in your AppDelegate.m.

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
             openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {
       // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
       BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
       // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed
       return wasHandled;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking a look, @ailvenge. Questions:

-What do you mean "install package"?

-Unfortunately, clicking that install link downloads about 10mb of the file, and then fails ("network error") every time, in any browser I try.

-So, I downloaded the source files from Github (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

-In that download, I can't figure out how to do anything (install package...build package...literally not sure what to click or type)

Comment: You can try by dropbox (if you can't download, save it to your dropbox and you won't need to worry about your browser): https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lbenmq5t98e8hy/facebook-ios-sdk-3.14.1.pkg

Answer (score 0):

Slightly older thread but to provide a clue: there's a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1535792689972842/) report on Facebook DEV as more people are facing the same issue. Let's hope they'll fix it asap.